# get the value of html5 <data-something="value"> with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

The other day I was reading the answers here in stackoverflow and I read, "jquery can get the value of the html5 `<data-something='value'>`", I read this when I was looking for something else so I just read and don't analyse this. And now I really need accomplish this task.

The question is: is it posible or I just misunderstand the reading?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
<div id="test" data-key="abcd">hahahah</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var value = $("#test").data("key");
alert(value); //This will show you "abcd"
</script>
```

I think data isn't only for HTML5 but also in HTML4

Comment: @figuedmundo `< data-something='value' >` doesn't make sense. HTML5 data tags are something different than what you are looking for. Patrick has what you need i think.

Comment: `data-` attributes were officially added in html5, but most browsers happily supported them (or any user-defined attributes) long before that. The point with the `data-` prefix is it keeps user-defined attributes organised, and it avoids clashes with other attribute names that might be officially added in future.

Comment: I want this becouse I'm thinking to push into the page some json data, { 'key': "value" } into < data-"key"="value">, and interact with jquery.click-> if attr("data-key") do something with the value.

Comment: It's an HTML5 only thing, but I think browsers understand it even if you are writing in HTML4 http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

Answer (score 4):

You can use `data()` and have jQuery attempt to decode the type and return the typed value.

If you want the raw string, use `attr("data-x")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="ch-content" data-type=plant></div>
```

get values from attributes "data-type"

```
var type = $(".ch-content").attr('data-type');
Console.log(type);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use native JavaScript:

```
<div id="test" data-key="abcd">hahahah</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var test= document.getElementById('test');
var keyCount = test.getAttribute('data-key');
</script>
```