# How to convert a set of html data-lat and data-long values into markers on a google map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a repeater that spits out the following code block, repeated for however many results match a users search:

```
<div class="development-result" data-lat="51.5812637" data-long="0.4203579999999647">
   <div class="dev-tmb pull-left">
        <img src="#">
   </div>      
   <div class="dev-det pull-left">
      <h2>town</h2>
      <h3>name</h3>
      <ul>
         <li class="from-price">from </li>
         <li class="miles">24.1 miles</li>
         <li class="view-dev"><a href="#">View</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to take the data-lat and data-long values along with the h2 and h3 to populate the marker variable in the javascript below.

```
var markers = [
 ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856],
 ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052],
 ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507],
 ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
 ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302]
];


function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25);
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: myLatlng
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]),
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
 }

} 

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Can this even be done? thanks in advance for any help/ advice

Comment: it can be done from the DOM but why can't you create the array at server ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.data()` method from jQuery check this answer [get the value of html5 <data-something="value"> with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103827/get-the-value-of-html5-data-something-value-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you want the "name" to come from, but this will put markers on the map with unique infowindows:

```
var markers = [];
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('development-result');
// alert(elements.length);
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    markers.push(new google.maps.LatLng(
    parseFloat(elements[i].getAttribute('data-lat')),
    parseFloat(elements[i].getAttribute('data-long'))));
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtwmmwar/)

More efficient (only process the data once, create the markers as you do that):

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtwmmwar/2/)

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('development-result');
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
    marker;
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(elements[i].getAttribute('data-lat')),
        parseFloat(elements[i].getAttribute('data-long'))),
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(elements[i].getAttribute('data-name') + "<br>" + this.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        };
    })(marker, i));
}
```